# git diff shows unicode symbols in angle brackets

Tags: git, unicode, diff

I have a file with unicode symbols (russian text).
When I fix some typo I use `git diff --color-words=.` to see the changes I've done.

In case of unicode (cyrillic) symbols I get some mess with angle brackets like so:

```
$ cat p1
привет

$ cat p2
Привет

$ git diff --color-words=. --no-index p1 p2
diff --git 1/p1 2/p2
index d0f56e1..d84c480 100644
--- 1/p1
+++ 2/p2
@@ -1 +1 @@
<D0><BF><9F>ривет
```

It looks like `git diff --color-words=.` is checking the difference between bytes and not between symbols as I expect.

Is there any way to tell `git` to work properly with unicode symbols?

**UPD** about my environment: I get the same on Mac OS and on Linux host.

My shell vars are:

```
BASH=/bin/bash
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
OSTYPE=darwin10.0
PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=iTerm.app
_=-l
```

I have reset git config to default settings like so:

```
$ git config -l
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

git version

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.3.5
```

Comment: That's not `git diff` showing you "angle brackets" but rather `less` - the default pager `git diff` calls. Try exporting `LESSOPTS=-R` or `LESSOPTS=-RX` and see if this helps.  There's also a problem with your question: you tell us precisely zero information about your environment.

Comment: I have updated the question with my env details. Also I tried to config git pager like so: `$ git config --global core.pager "less -R"` and this does not help.

Comment: I have tried this also:

`$ GIT_PAGER='' git diff --no-index --color-words=. p1 p2`
`���ривет`

`$ GIT_PAGER='' git diff --no-index --color-words=. --no-color p1 p2`
`п�ривет`

Comment: `--word-diff-regex=.` works on byte level and breaks multi-byte character. Sadly this option does not support codepoint range either (tried posix and pcre notation but none worked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me was to use git difftool.

I wrote this tool https://github.com/chestozo/dmp based on https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/.

Sometimes it also gives better diff comparing to `git diff --color-words=.` :)

Answer (score 39):

For me `less` — the git pager — was to blame (thanks @kostix). Experiment by disabling the pager altogether:

```
git --no-pager diff p1 p2
```

My case was commit messages containing emojis; it's fundamentally the same problem though.

```
$ git log --oneline
93a1866 <U+1F43C>

$ git --no-pager log --oneline
93a1866 

$ export LESS='--raw-control-chars'
$ git log --oneline
93a1866 

$ git config --global core.pager 'less --raw-control-chars'
$ git log --oneline
93a1866
```

**NB**: the `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS` option causes `less` to pass through ANSI color escapes, but will still munge other control chars (emoji included). My `less` is globally configured with `--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS` and my git pager with `--raw-control-chars` as above.

Comment: Important part was `--color-words=.` because I do want to see diff by symbol.

And this is what I get running `git --no-pager show --color-words=.`: `���ривет`. Same for `git --no-pager diff --color-words=. --no-index p1 p2`.

Comment: `git config --global core.pager 'less --raw-control-chars'` was just what I needed to fix git-log display issues!

Comment: Doesn't fix for me; anybody has other suggestions?  I already had
    `pager = less -FrSX` under `[core]` in my *~/.gitconfig* but it doesn't help.  My environment *LANG* is `en_US.UTF-8`; env *LESS* is `-M -I -R` (trying to change `-R` to `-r` doesn't change behaviour).

Answer (score 21):

For me best solution to this is setting `export LESSCHARSET=utf-8`.

In this case both `git log -p` and `git diff` shows unicode without problems.

Comment: doesn't work for me. I have `pager = less -rFX` in `.gitconfig` and this is what I get  https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/2p3703271r0m060s1J34/s.png?v=2d60f213

Comment: what do you see for `git diff --color-words=.` ?

Comment: Do you have LANG set?
Mine is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Here is what I get with `git diff` and `git diff --color-words=.` https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wt9iysevw2xeyn/Screenshot%202016-12-25%2023.09.02.png?dl=0

Comment: Here is when you have changed Cyrillic word
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x67c5jdngrhgp2/Screenshot%202016-12-25%2023.15.24.png?dl=0

Comment: same here `$ echo $LANG >>> en_US.UTF-8`. I see this answer also here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/19436421/449345 - but somehow it doesn't help :/

Comment: This solved it for me. Created a new environment variable `LESSCHARSET` set to `utf-8` and `git log`/`diff` now displays norwegian letters ÆØÅ properly insted of `<C3><85>` etc. OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

For several platforms setting `LANG` to `C.UTF-8` (or `en_US.UTF-8`, etc.) would work:

```
$ echo '人' >test1.txt && echo '丁' >test2.txt
$ LANG=C.UTF-8 git diff --no-index --word-diff=plain --word-diff-regex=. -- test1.txt test2.txt
diff --git a/test1.txt b/test2.txt
index 3ef0891..3773917 100644
--- a/test1.txt
+++ b/test2.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
[-人-]{+丁+}
```

However, `LANG` doesn't seem to be honored on some platforms (such as [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1671)):

```
$ echo '人' >test1.txt && echo '丁' >test2.txt
$ LANG=C.UTF-8 git diff --no-index --word-diff=plain --word-diff-regex=. -- test1.txt test2.txt
diff --git a/test1.txt b/test2.txt
index 3ef0891..3773917 100644
--- a/test1.txt
+++ b/test2.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
<E4>[-<BA><BA>-]{+<B8><81>+}
```

A workaround on these platforms is to provide raw bytes for UTF-8 chars (e.g. `$'[^\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]*'` for `'.'`) to git diff:

```
$ echo '人' >test1.txt && echo '丁' >test2.txt
$ git diff --no-index --word-diff=plain --word-diff-regex=$'[^\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]*' -- test1.txt test2.txt
diff --git a/test1.txt b/test2.txt
index 3ef0891..3773917 100644
--- a/test1.txt
+++ b/test2.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
[-人-]{+丁+}
```

Comment: The LANG var in my case is `en_US.UTF-8` and it doesn't help much.  


`git diff --color-words=. --word-diff-regex=$'[^\x80-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]*'` is a good one! thank you ) will check it out!

Comment: If you are using --word-diff-regex, it'd be better to use --word-diff=color instead of --color-words (which is a combination of both). Furthermore, you can set `diff.wordRegex` so that you can provide only --word-diff=color in the future, and git will use the configured regex for word diff.

Comment: Be careful with rendering UTF8 chars in git diffs. Its very possible to sneak some malicious code by hiding it with dubious UTF8 characters (zero width characters i'm looking at you)

Answer (score 1):

[toolbear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260108/747050)'s answer didn't work for me, since even with `git --no-pager diff` I saw unreadable characters as well (not brackets, but unreadable), so `less` was not the core problem.

I tried a ton of things, but the only thing, which helped is to include into .git\config explicit conversion from Cyrillic to utf-8 (I'm using windows 7)

```
[pager]
diff = iconv.exe -f cp1251 -t utf-8 | less
```

note, I change specifically `pager.diff` here, since I had encoding problems only with `diff` command. For some weird reason `log` and `reflog` was working fine with me. But if you have encoding problems with other commands too, you should change pager for all the commands, like this:

```
[core]
...
pager = iconv.exe -f cp1251 -t utf-8 | less
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a lot of reports xterm is not really able to print Unicode characters in some cases. Maybe at least a starting point for a solution.

Comment: I this case the problem is in 2 bytes, used to represent a unicode symbol in shell.
While `git diff` only knows to deal with 1 bytes symbols.
I am not sure it is xterm problem.

Comment: Well... Doesn't look like ... at least this worked for me
diff --git a/README b/README
index e69de29..b562a56 100644
--- a/README
+++ b/README
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+µÜäčřúůжжвыаьь