# Make git diff show UTF8 encoded characters properly

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8

I have a file with Swedish characters in it (åäö) encoded with UTF8.

If I `cat` the file it displays fine, but if I do `git diff` the special characters are printed, for example, as <F6>.

Example `git diff` output:

```
-            name: 'Magler<F6>d, S<F6>der<E5>sen',
```

What I wanted to see:

```
-            name: 'Magleröd, Söderåsen',
```

I found another question related to git and encoding problems: [git, msysgit, accents, utf-8, the definitive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers)
It says all problems should be fixed in git version 1.7.10. I have version 1.8.1.2

What can I do to make git diff properly display åäö?

Comment: Are you sure your file is UTF-8? `xF6` is the ISO-8859-1 code for `ö`, and `xE5` is the code for `å`.

Comment: `file -bi filename.txt` gives me
text/plain; charset=utf-8

Comment: @Tobbe I suspect `file` is simply noticing that it's not ASCII, and not doing any extensive testing to verify that's a valid UTF-8 file (which it wouldn't be if the actual byte values are 0xf6 and 0xe5 as matt suggests, because the bytes immediately following do not have bit 7 set, which would be required to be valid UTF-8 code points). `file` may just "guess" at UTF-8 - I'm sure it's not looping through all available encodings and testing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@matt and @twalberg were correct. The file wasn't actually UTF-8 encoded. Trying to figure this out wasn't helped by the fact that my terminal (hterm) can't input åäö properly (but it can display and copy/paste them)...

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 in.txt > out_utf-8.txt
```

solved my issue

Comment: You can actually view the diff without writing to an intermediate file, even though the command line is a bit verbose: `git diff --color | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 | less -r` where `--color` forces `git` to output ascii color into the pipe and `-r` forces `less` to stream those color escapes to the terminal.

Comment: In case it happens to someone else, I tried the command, but iconv told me it doesn't know the utf8 encoding, getting the encoding list with iconv -l, I found the encoding with the name: utf-8, so the command for me was: ```git diff --color | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 | less -r```

Answer (score 80):

`git` is dumping out raw bytes.  In this case, it doesn't care what your file's encoding is.  The highlighted `<F6>` you're seeing is coming from `less`, which is presumably configured as your `PAGER`.  Try setting:

```
LESSCHARSET=UTF-8
```

Comment: FYI, if you want to make the change permanent (instead of having to use the command `export LESSCHARSET=utf-8` every time you log into your machine), just add it to your `~/.bashrc` file

Comment: Another option is to set the env var in your `~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config`. In my case, I have `pager = LESSCHARSET=utf-8 less -R` in the `[core]` section.

Comment: For anyone running Docker: remember you'll want to use `ENV` inside of a Dockerfile to set the environment variable system-wide. i.e.: `ENV LESSCHARSET=utf-8`.

Comment: Another possiblity, if you are using powershell, is to set [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8 as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205297/the-output-of-git-diff-is-not-handled-correctly-in-powershell

Answer (score 3):

git log will be opened by less not vi.

So you should set lang to less.

`$ export LESSCHARSET=utf-8 && git log`