# Generating git diff

Tags: git

I'm trying to generate diff from file with encoding "UTF-8 Unicode". 
This is C source code but contains Asians characters(in comments).
I've added only few lines but the diff shows several others due to encoding. When I use difftool with kdiff3 it works correctly.

After some investigation I realize that the temporary file, created by diff, has other encoding iso-8859-1.

Can you give me some advise how to overcome this?

best regards
Pawel

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435071/make-git-diff-show-utf8-encoded-characters-properly

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` and most of the other [one-byte character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) do not have a signature and there is no way to auto-detect them. The program that reads such a file usually uses a default (configured) encoding to interpret the bytes to as characters. Even for `UTF-8` the program needs to get a hint in order to not mistake it for `ISO-8859-1` or other encoding.

Comment: So far I've tried several method from the mentioned thread and none works for me. I just need to generate a patch file with only my changes.