# Non-UTF8 Characters in Git Diff (like ESC[1;33m] )

Tags: git, encoding, utf-8

Git diff keeps showing non-UTF8 characters.

Suggestion from [Make git diff show UTF8 encoded characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435071/make-git-diff-show-utf8-encoded-characters-properly), I have tried setting `export LESSCHARSET=UTF-8` in my `.zshrc` but it still does not work.

Comment: Can you, please, add content from the picture as text. It will be much more readable and you have more chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are color-setting codes. Either instruct your `less` to pass them through (via, e.g., `-R` as an option or `R` in the environment `LESS` setting) or disable colored diffs.

Git defaults to setting `LESS="FRX"` in the environment if no `LESS` setting is set yet.  To make this fail you must be overriding the default, e.g., by providing your own `LESS` setting or by using command-line options.

Comment: Thank you! I did `git config --global core.pager "less -r"` and it sets `pager = less -r` in `.gitconfig`'s `core` section.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
export LESS='FRX --mouse'
export LESSCHARSET=UTF-9
```