# The output of git diff is not handled correctly in powershell

Tags: windows, git, powershell, character-encoding, git-diff

I have read several QAs to this problem, but none provided an answer. There is a workaround, which I state here again, but I want to understand and solve the problem.

**Problem**

The issue is that executing the command `git diff reva revb | Out-File mypatch.patch` in powershell produces "garbage characters" in place of e.g. German umlauts (├ñ instead of ä).

**Investigation**

When I perform `$Env:LESSCHARSET="utf8"` as suggested in some QAs, I do get correct output in the terminal, but once it is redirected to the file `mypatch.patch` the umlauts (and other characters) are mangled. Even `git --no-pager diff reva revb` results in correct output in the terminal. But as soon as you want to pipe that to a file, it is wrong. What you see is *not* what you get!

It seems to me that the input to `Out-File` is already mangled and thus setting the `-Encoding` argument does not change anything. I don't think `Out-File` is to blame here. For instance, the command `$mypatch = git diff reva revb` (even with --no-pager added before diff) results in a variable where e.g. Euro symbol or umlauts appear mangled (Ôé¼ instead of €) when that variable is printed to the terminal.

I tried powershell 5.1 and the open source powershell core 6.0.4 on Windows 10 (1709). I use git 2.18.0.windows.1. It works fine with the windows commandline (cmd), thus the simple workaround is to call from the powershell console:

**Workaround**

`cmd /c "git diff reva revb > mypatch.patch"`

**Question**

How does this work with powershell only?

Comment: Did you try avoiding the pipeline: `Out-File -InputObject (git diff reva revb) -Path mypatch.patch -Encoding utf8`?

Comment: Visually that might be avoiding the pipeline but it is still going to be used in the background. I suspect the result will be the same.

Comment: You could do `git diff reva revb | Out-File -Encoding "UTF8" mypatch.patch`, but that will produce a file with a **BOM** (Byte-Order-Mark). If that is unwanted, use `$Utf8NoBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False; [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($MyPath, $MyFile, $Utf8NoBom)`

Comment: @DarkLite1 This does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by a wrong setting of `[Console]::OutputEncoding`. If it is not set to UTF8, try setting it: `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`.

It does not matter if you then use `$Env:LESSCHARSET`, respectively I believe it's not used anymore.

Comment: Au contraire, on my machine (tm), only the `$Env:LESSCHARSET` fix alone is enough and sufficient to make `git diff`'s output render correctly. The OutputEncoding setting does not hurt, but does not fix the symptom of garbled special characters (e.g. `<C3><BC>` instead of `ü`).

Comment: @ojdo As I stated, it's rendered correctly in the terminal, but if you redirect the output to a file it's garbage and only the setting in that answer fixed the problem for me.