# git diff --name-status showing files that does not exists

Tags: git

I try in a Azure DevOps pipeline to zip and deploy files, listed via Git. The problem I encounter is that I use the following command to list the files to deploy even for a previous commit because the deliveries are not always done at time:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d
```

<s>but I found that a file has been listed for a folder that does not exists anymore and with git log, I didn't find a trace of the file neither.</s>

Strangely, the file is appearing in strange way in the output of the command with double quotes mentioned as "Modified" :

[image: diff output]

***PS : sorry the missing info is that the line with double quote ... \303\252 is the line causing my problems.I produced the output with git diff --name-status --diff-filter=d command, in fact \303\252 are a issue from the encoding conversion between ansi 1252 and UTF8 (Suivi_Entête_cr_old.asp).***

<s>I don't understand that git log does not give me answers and the fact the file is a modified one but not existing. I suspect that the folder has been deleted but when?
I don't find the way to have a correct and detailed answer of the problem.</s>

***PS2: with the command git -c core.quotepath=false --no-pager diff --name-only :***
*Appli_web_livre/credits_invendus/Suivi_Ent??te_cr_old.asp*

***PS3 : if the console powershell use ASCII encoding, i have the ?? replacing the ê , but changing to UTF8 the console:***

```bsh
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

***i obtain the right string.***

Duplicate with [The output of git diff is not handled correctly in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205297/the-output-of-git-diff-is-not-handled-correctly-in-powershell)

Comment: For the same commit, can you compare the output of : `git diff --name-status` and `git diff --name-status --diff-filter=d` ?

Comment: two extra notes : 1. it is preferrable to write the output of commands as text instead of a screen capture ; 2. can you describe the command you used to produce said output ? `--name-only` would not output a status letter on the left column.

Comment: The double quotes are not all that important, relevant, they are there because the path contains escaped characters. I am wondering if those could be the reason why you're finding its containing directory in an unexpected state. How are you looking for the directory/files when you mention they are not to be seen?

Comment: Uh... gonna disagree with Ondrej on that one.  The double-quotes are super important because they're telling you that whole string is a filename in the root directory, not the path they otherwise appear to be.

Comment: First of all, you should check all of the above files which are stored in git or not? You use `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`, you replace `master` by `your branch`.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I am perplex but open to the notion I am wrong. The double quoted path is quoted because its rooted elsewhere or has different meaning relative to the not quoted paths around it? Those are not in their entirety filenames or are rooted at a different place? Where? However, I've double checked...  quoted (just like unquoted) paths appear to still be rooted at (repo root for `git diff --name-only`, or cwd for `git status`), but  quoting is used for names w/ escaped characters (but not for, even trailing, space; that's actually a bit evil)). Is this behavior new/specific to 2.28?

Comment: The path is double quoted because it contains characters that Git thought should be quoted, namely the `\303\252` part. This is controlled by the `core.quotePath` setting. The Git code that quotes names is not self-consistent; Junio Hamano proposed a fix recently on the Git mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand that git log does not give me answers and the fact the file is a modified one but not existing. I suspect that the folder has been deleted but when?

In an important sense, Git doesn't actually store *folders*.  It stores *files* that have long names that your OS demands be chopped up, such as `Appli_web_livre/credits_invendus/CR_ajout_article.asp`.  That's all one file's name: it's not a folder holding a folder holding a file, it's just a name.  It's your OS that demands that Git create a folder `Appli_web_livre` first, and so on.

The way Git deals with this is that, whenever it needs to create a work-tree file named (say) `Appli_web_livre/credits_invendus/CR_ajout_article.asp`, it will create a folder `credits_invendus` within a folder `Appli_web_livre`, so that the OS will be happy.  This does lead to problems sometimes, such as when you have a *file* named `Appli_web_livre` in the way.  (The internal code in Git, where it's building up OS operations to perform for a `git checkout` or `git reset` or similar, calls this a "D/F conflict": directory where file is needed or vice versa.)

This matters for various reasons, including:

> I don't find the way to have a correct and detailed answer of the problem.

The `git diff` command you mention:

> ```
> git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d
> ```

generally compares *two commits*.  (There are a lot of exceptions to this but since you mentioned an AzureOps pipeline, I'm guessing here that you are using this mode.)  To make this happen, you must specify both commits:

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2>
```

The commit named at the left, *`commit1`* here, becomes the left side of the difference operation, and the commit named at the right—*`commit2`*—becomes the right side.<sup>1</sup>  Each commit holds a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about when you made the commit (or when whoever made the commit, made it).  If there are files with the same names on the left and right, those are the same file.  If there's a file `Appli_web_livre/credits_invendus/CR_ajout_article.asp` on the left, but not on the right, then the file was `D`eleted;<sup>2</sup> and if there is one on the right but not the left, then the file is newly-created (`A`dded).  Otherwise, if the two copies don't match, the file is `M`odified.  There are a few other possible letter-codes (see footnote 2 for `R`enamed, and `T`ype-changed shows up when one side has a symbolic link and the other side has a file, for instance) but `A`, `D`, and `M` are the three main ones of interest here.

Normally, for any file that's exactly the same, Git says nothing at all, and for any file that's changed in any way—including being newly added, or deleted, or just modified—Git will print the file's name and then show a set of changes that, if applied, will produce the right-side file from the left-side file.  The `--name-only` flag tells `git diff` to produce only the names of added, deleted, or modified files.

The `--diff-filter` option tells `git diff` that, for some changes, it should suppress everything, and for others, it should print whatever is left to print: the name and the status letter, and without `--name-only`, the change as well.  The letters you put after the `=` sign are the ones to be printed, or to be suppressed.  Uppercase letters tell Git which ones to print:

```
--diff-filter=AD
```

for instance would print any `A`dded and `D`eleted files, but omit modified files or those with any other letter code.  Lowercase, on the other hand, means *exclude this type*, so:

```
--diff-filter=d
```

means *exclude `D` files*, i.e., print `A`dded, `M`modified, `R`enamed, or `T`ype-changed files, but not `D`eleted files.<sup>3</sup>  As the status here is `M`, that part is fine.

What this means is that the two input commits both contain a file whose name is `Appli_web_livre/credits_invendus/CR_ajout_article.asp` and the two copies of those files differ.  Without knowing what the input commits are, there is little more we can say about this.

---

<sup>1</sup>The `-R` flag reverses the sides.  This isn't required with this form of diff since you could just reverse the two arguments, but some `git diff` operations use your work-tree contents, or the index contents, or an implied `HEAD`, and for these, the `-R` flag is particularly convenient, or even necessary.

<sup>2</sup>When the `--find-renames` option is enabled, a deleted file on the left can be paired with a newly-created file on the right.  This kind of pairing-up then tells `git diff` to declare that these files, despite the name change, are *the same file*, in the same way that a *copy* of the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) might actually *be* the Ship of Theseus.  In this case, though, that did not happen.

<sup>3</sup>The full set of possible letters is listed as ABCDMRTUX.  Status code `B` is only possible when using the `-B` option and indicates a broken pairing, but I've never been able to get it to come out in any test.  Status code `U` can only occur when you're in the middle of an incomplete mere.  Status code `C` can only occur when you have enabled `--find-copies`.  Status code `X` indicates a bug in the diff code and therefore should never occur.  In practice, your `git diff` should produce only A, C, D, M, R, or T; and C and R should only occur if you have copy and/or rename detection enabled.  Since `git diff` obeys user configurations, this will depend on your user configuration.

Because `git diff` obeys user configuration, scripts should rarely use `git diff` itself, but rather should invoke one of the more specific plumbing commands, such as `git diff-tree`.

---

#### Additional specifics

> I found that a file has been listed for a folder that does not exists anymore and with git log, I didn't find a trace of the file neither.

You don't show what command you used with `git log`, but if you ran:

```
git log Appli_web_livre/credits_invendus/CR_ajout_article.asp
```

for instance, this turns on what `git log` calls *history simplification*.  The goal of history simplification is to eliminate from view any commit that doesn't affect what you see *now*, in the commit you start with.  So if the file is gone *now*, you often won't see any of the commits that *do* have the file.  For more detail, see my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48819299/1256452) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50724301/1256452).  If the files were accidentally deleted via merge, this is not sufficient; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556222/1256452) as well.

> Strangely, the file is appearing in strange way in the output of the command with double quotes ...

Files are double-quoted when at least one character in the file name requires quoting, or—sometimes but not always—when there is a space in the file's name.  [The `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) describes this under the `core.quotePath` variable:

> Commands that output paths (e.g. `ls-files`, `diff`), will quote "unusual" characters in the pathname by enclosing the pathname in double-quotes and escaping those characters with backslashes in the same way C escapes control characters (e.g. `\t` for TAB, `\n` for LF, `\\` for backslash) or bytes with values larger than 0x80 (e.g. octal `\302\265` for "micro" in UTF-8). If this variable is set to false, bytes higher than 0x80 are not considered "unusual" any more. Double-quotes, backslash and control characters are always escaped regardless of the setting of this variable. A simple space character is not considered "unusual". Many commands can output pathnames completely verbatim using the `-z` option. The default value is true.

This particular file name has `\303\252` in it, and by default, that gets the string quoted.

(Whitespace quoting is inconsistent between `git status` and some other commands, and there is some code improvement coming in a future Git release to fix this.)