# VB6 source files containing accented characters don't diff properly in git?

Tags: git, vb6, git-diff

I'm opening a project in **VB6** to make some changes and everything works fine. Preparing it to upload to **Git**, when I type `git diff` to compare the changes, I noticed that it's messing up my comments with accents, what could cause some conflicts with my co-workers' git codes.

for example:

```
distan = distan + Int(distancia)  ' s<F3> soma se for maior que 1 --- at<E9> 15 horas
```

should be

```
distan = distan + Int(distancia)  ' só soma se for maior que 1 --- até 15 horas
```

It's happening in this particular project only. I have not seen it happening when submitting a merge request in git with other projects.

Comment: Is this a problem with git diff or with VB6 saving the files in a different encoding than the original?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're making comments in Brazilian Portuguese. Muito bem, que legal.

Did you try one of these pages?

[git, msysgit, accents, utf-8, the definitive answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854967/git-msysgit-accents-utf-8-the-definitive-answers)

Or possibly:

[Make git diff show UTF8 encoded characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435071/make-git-diff-show-utf8-encoded-characters-properly)

If either works, please let us know which one helped and specifically why this project differed from your other projects.