# 'git log' output encoding issues in Windows 10 CLI terminal

Tags: git, terminal, character-encoding, command-line-interface, locale

#### Problem

How can I make `git log` command output properly displayed in the Windows CLI terminal?

#### Example

[image: Git commands sequence leading to the problem]

As you can see, I can type diacritical characters properly, but on `git log`, the output is somehow escaped. According to the [UTF-8 encoding table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256), the codes between angle brackets (`<` and `>`) from the output correspond to the previously typed `git config` parameters.

I have tried to set `LESSCHARSET` environment variable to `utf-8` as suggested in [one of the answers for similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19436421/2443502), but then the output is garbled:

[image: 'git log' output after setting LESSCHARSET=utf8]

I know `.git/config` is encoded properly with UTF-8 as it's handled by `gitk` as expected.

[image: Proper gitk output]

Here is the `locale` command output if necessary:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The output is the same also in pure [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway):

[image]

so I believe the problem is shell-independent and relates to Git or its configuration itself.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in  "[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)"?

Comment: Yes, I tried several code pages including 65001 (UTF-8) without any result. It seems chcp command has no influence on how git log output is displayed. It's always displayed in the same way.

Comment: Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but why do you use the Windows command prompt at all instead of Git Bash? It is better suited to using Git, the window is resizeable up to full screen, the prompt automatically shows you which branch you are on etc.

Comment: It's not stupid @kriegaex, it's good actually. I'm using git-bash wrapped into ConEmu for everyday use. The result is the same http://i.imgur.com/hMKz9D3r.png. I've described my problem giving examples with cmd.exe to not confuse people with other dependent tools am using as I believe the problem is shell independent and relates to Git or its configuration itself.

Comment: @jthill thanks, this answer seems to do it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55674760/4592648

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Okay, I experimented a bit and found out that Windows Git commands actually need UNIX variables like `LC_ALL` in order to display Polish (or other UTF-8 characters) correctly. Just try this command:

```
set LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

Then enjoy the result. Here is what happened on my console (font "Consolas", no `chcp` necessary):

[image: Windows console CMD]

---

**Update:**

- Well, in order for Windows commands like `type` (display file on console) to work correctly, you do need `chcp 65001`.
- And if you prefer commands from Git Bash like `cat` you profit from the aforementioned `set LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`.

[image: Windows console CMD, part 2]

---

**Update 2: How to make the changes permanent**

As user *mono blaine* said, create an environment variable `LC_ALL` and assign it the value `C.UTF-8`, either globally or for your own user profile only (sorry for the German screenshot):

[image: Create environment variable]

Next time you open a command processor console (cmd.exe) you should see the variable value when issuing the command `echo %LC_ALL%`. In PowerShell you should see it when issuing `$env:LC_ALL`.

The simplest way to make the UTF-8 code page permanent ist to open `regeedit` and add a new value named `Autorun` of type string to section
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` and assign it the value `chcp 65001`.

[image: Registration editor]

Henceforth, this command will be executed each time you open a new cmd.exe console. You even see its output in the new window: "Aktive Codepage: 65001." (or similar in your respective language).

Oh, by the way: In order to display a UTF-8 encoded file correctly in PowerShell you can use `Get-Content -encoding UTF8 file.txt` or `cat -encoding UTF8 file.txt` (`cat` being an alias for `Get-Content` in PowerShell).

Comment: Set `LC_ALL` is not needed by git itself. Other tools -- shiped with the git installaion -- like `less`, which is the default pager / see [core.pager](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) are using the `LC_ALL` value. Other valid values are the localized lang e.g.: `LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8` for the germans.

Comment: you can set the environment-variable from commandline using `setx LC_ALL C.UTF-8`

Comment: Powershell 6 in ConEmu, it was enough to add `$env.LC_ALL='ClUTF-8'` to `$Profile`

Comment: Had encoding issue with rscript utility (command line tool for running r code), this advice helped to fix it also. Thanks!

Answer (score 73):

If anyone is interested in the PowerShell equivalent of `set LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`, that is:

```
$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'
```

However this works only for the current session. To make it permanent, two possibilities:

- create an environment variable named `LC_ALL` with the value `C.UTF-8`
- or put `$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'` in your `$Profile` file

Comment: Or add it to your PowerShell profile (I prefer this to the global setting because I use the same profile – via git – on multiple machines).

Comment: The profile file can be edited by for example running:
notepad $profile
Then add a line somewhere as mono blaine suggested, 
$env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8'

Comment: With PowerShell 6 + ConEmu on Windows 10: this works, nothing else was needed

Answer (score 11):

I am using **Git** via **PowerShell Core v7.0.3** inside [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/terminal) on Windows 10.

I have been browsing through answers and tried many of them. The solutions that worked for me were:

- [Change a Git setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28260108): `git config --global core.pager 'less --raw-control-chars'`
- Add `$env:LC_ALL = 'C.UTF-8'` [to the current PowerShell profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441828)

These solutions both work separately. I chose to use the Git command as the problem  seems to be related to Git, and PowerShell profile stays cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the Git setting. The Git settings works for me, but also found that setting `$env:LESSCHARSET='utf-8'` works fine as well for the PowerShell 5 in the Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 7):

I use [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) on Windows 10. As for me, four settings make the appearance as my expectation.

- `env` setting. Add `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`,`LESSCHARSET=UTF-8` to `PATH` globally.
- `git` config. `git config --global i18n.logOutputEncoding utf-8`.
- Git Bash setting. Set *Options* → *Text* → *Character set* to `utf-8`. Or set `locale` and `Character set` both to `default`. It is smart enough to choose the correct `encoding`.

Done.

Comment: I use `git` on Windows command prompt, and the first two steps solved the issue for my case.

Comment: first two steps helps to solve vs-code timeline encoding as well

Answer (score 3):

My solution (git log called from PowerShell 7.3.6 on Win 10)

```
[console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Comment: that is what worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the Windows PowerShell command prompt instead of the default one (<kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>).

Comment: It works like a charm for Korean.

Answer (score 1):

I had such problem on Linux. And the problem was that I did not generate locales. So my output of `locale` was containing all "C" letters, without UTF-8.

To solve this, I uncommented `en_US.UTF-8` and `ru_RU.UTF-8` in /etc/locale.gen. Then I run localectl set-locale LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 and rebooted. And relogined to the system. After that Cyrillic was displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git config --global core.pager 'less --raw-control-chars'
 
#Or

git config --global core.pager 'more'
```