# How do I change charset / locale in conemu?

Tags: git-bash, conemu, mintty

I am using gitbash via conemu.

I have a charset issue where the chars look wrong in gitbash via conemu and gitbash directly.

I fixed it in gitbash by setting the locale in .minttyrc to ..

```
BoldAsFont=-1
Locale=en_US
Charset=UTF-8
```

But this doesn't fix it in gitbash when launched via conemu.

Any ideas where I would change conemu settings to address locale or to get it to pick up .minttyrc settings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in "[git log output encoding issues on Windows 10 command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416262/6309)", can you check your conemu session is:

- using the Consolas font
- has set the LC_ALL variable:

  ```
  set LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
  ```

Check then if git bash still display the wrong charset.

Comment: thanks man ... 4 hours later .... export LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 ... did the job ...... worth noting that ..... locale -a ...... outputs available locales