# git log - show UTF-8 characters

Tags: git, utf-8, macos-sierra, git-diff, iterm2

I am using `git` client under macOS Sierra 10.12.3, with iTerm2.

I have source files which contain Chinese Simplified & Chinese Traditional characters. Whenever I do `git diff`, it shows like below:

[image]

In NetBeans IDE's `git` tool, it manages to show diff in Chinese characters.

[image]

I read seems `git diff` is using `less` to display. Setting `export LESSCHARSET=UTF-8` fails.

What shall I configure to make iTerm show git diff correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Can you test http://stackoverflow.com/a/41843925/6309 and setting `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8`

Comment: @VonC Tried your suggestion, still same not fixed :(

Comment: And with `chcp 65001`? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/41416262/6309), also http://stackoverflow.com/a/38694885/6309

Comment: I am running on MacOS not Windows.

Comment: Right. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262053/6309 then? Or http://serverfault.com/a/414763/783 (for `less`, used by Git)

Comment: Is this a problem both in iTerm2 and the standard Terminal? Do you get correct output from `git --no-pager log`? (On a side note, `less` displays unsupported characters as a hex number in angle brackets (controlled by `LESSBINFMT`), like this: `<E9>`, by default, so there is something non-standard somewhere).