# How to put $env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8' on profile file of Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I saw in that answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41441828/8926795) that I can put $env:LC_ALL='C.UTF-8' on profile file to run every time I open Powershell. I just paste that on the file this way:

[image: Profile file]

But it doesn't work. Did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file path of your `$PROFILE` file implies that you're running *on Windows*, whereas the command you're using is for *Unix-like* platforms (or programs such as `git.exe`, which even on Windows act as they do on Unix-like platforms).

To make your PowerShell consoles on Windows use UTF-8, place the following in your `$PROFILE` file:

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding =
                    New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

For background information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375).