# Unable to delete remote branch with name <A4><A4><BD><BC>

Tags: git, character-encoding, gitlab, special-characters, gitlab-ce

Tried to delete the weird characters branch from remote gitlab project but no success.

`git branch -av` listing the weird characters branch as `remotes/origin/<A4><A4><BD><BC>`

`git push origin --delete "<A4><A4><BD><BC>"` showing no such remote branch.

With `git ls-remote --heads` lists the branch like below.

```
ec9dd6610c545bca163221c11843ad03f642cd62 refs/heads/▒▒▒▒

git push origin --delete refs/remotes/origin/▒▒▒▒
! [remote rejected] origin/▒▒▒▒ (deny deleting a hidden ref)
 error: failed to push some refs to gitlab repository
```

Have tried with `gitk-GUI(Ubuntu)` & `Windows Git-GUI` also but no success.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139067/git-log-output-encoding-issues-on-windows-10-command-prompt/41416262#41416262) As per the following link even tried on `Windows-10 Command prompt` and `Git-Bash` as well, but still unable to view the masked characters branch to delete.

Comment: Does the branch really exist in the remote repository? You can have a check by `git ls-remote | grep 'refs/remotes/origin/'`. In most cases, there should not be any ref under `refs/remotes/origin` in a remote repository.

Comment: GitLab GUI shows - `500 - Whoops, something went wrong on our end.` error i have cloned the repository locally and with `git branch -av` able to view the branch.

Comment: `git ls-remote | grep 'refs/remotes/origin/'` this returns only repository.

Comment: Then you can't delete it as it does not exist in the remote repository. You can then run `git ls-remote --heads` to check if the branch with weird characters exist. It's supposed to be `refs/heads/foo` instead. If you find it , you can use `git push origin --delete refs/heads/foo` to delete it, and then use `git remote update origin --prune` or `git fetch origin --prune` to remove `refs/remotes/origin/foo` in the local repository.

Comment: `git ls-remote --heads` shows the weird characters branch.

Comment: with the above commands it got deleted successfully. but again `git ls-remote --heads` command shows the weird characters branch.

Comment: Replace `foo` with the real name.

Comment: Yes tried with real name `refs/heads/▒▒▒▒`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225461/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-kishore).

Comment: Possible solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't find any solution.  Any way is there to delete it?